# Sorting Arrays by first parameter in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to organize data once It has been looped and joined.

Edited: to show implementation of end part

```
const request = require('request');




const options = {
    url: 'https://stockx.com/api/browse?&_search=$jordan 3 unc',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
        'User-Agent': 'stockx'
    }
};

request(options, function(err, res, data) {
    const json = JSON.parse(data);

    console.log(json.Products[0].shoe)
    console.log(json.Products[1].media.imageUrl)

    for (var n = 1; n < 25; n++){





/* ^ loop through array and then reorganize and join them below */

    const sizes = [json.Products[n].market.lastSaleSize];
    const sales = [json.Products[n].market.lastSale];


    const join = sizes.concat(sales);



    v
```

The problem is [ size: sale] is returned but sizes are all out of order, is there a sort() function can reorder the sizes in numerical order but maintaining the connected sale price?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @Barmar yeah i've tried that and cannot figure it out

Comment: Show what you tried and we'll help you fix it. We're not going to write it for you.

Comment: okay sounds good I will paste it in here shortly thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort function by default compares the values as strings. To sort the [price:sale] correctly, you need to cast the price to a number, before doing the comparison. The sort function for your problem then looks like this:

```
yourResult.sort((tupleA, tupleB) => Number(tupleA[0]) - Number(tupleB[0]))
```

The problem with your code is, that the data structure you're working with is an array with two elements. Those elements can only be accessed by the index. `arr[0]` or `arr[1]`.

---

Answer to your question below:

I think you changed the data structure a bit since the original post. Yes, the values are put into 1 single array when using concat.

---

The current solution you have right now seems to be a mix of copy-pastes. Let me explain you how I would solve this problem:

1. Your data:

```
const json = JSON.parse(data);
```

2. As there are empty values in lastSale, let's get rid of those products by using a filter:

```
const filteredProducts = json.Products.filter(function(product) {
        return product.market.lastSaleSize !== null &&
               product.market.lastSale !== null
      })
```

More about filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

3. For all the products, you want the lastSaleSize and the lastSale. A good data structure for this would be an array with objects of this format:

```
{ lastSaleSize: X, lastSale: Y }
```

This can achieved with the `map` function. For each product it receives, it returns a new object:

```
const sales = filteredProducts.map(function(product) {
        return {
            lastSaleSize: product.market.lastSaleSize,
            lastSale: product.market.lastSale,
        }
    })
```

More about the map function: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

4. The last step is sorting. Each item of sales is now an object with the keys `lastSaleSize` and `lastSale`. Therefore it is possible to access the lastSaleSize with the dot-operator (`.lastSaleSize`). As lastSaleSize is still a string, it a cast to a Number is needed.

```
const result = sales.sort(function(saleA, saleB) {
    return Number(saleA.lastSaleSize) - Number(saleB.lastSaleSize)
})
```

Comment: is that because I am joining those two elements together? when running the loop the values come back separately before joining them with concat
```6
325
8.5
327```

Comment: this does indeed work , Thank you so much David for taking the time to explain that, I am new to JS ( Graphic/web designer here) and trying to learn new things during quarantine which unfortunately results from a lot copy and paste errors from watching tutorials. While I have read through a lot of documentation, It is a lot to take in at once!

Answer (score 0):

The solution you were given is the easiest way.

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
  return parseFloat(a[0]) - parseFloat(b[0])
})
```

However, I created a function that will sort your array by the first value of every array in main array of arrays

```
function sort_array_by_first_value(array){

  sorted_array = []  //the new array where will will store the sorted values

  while(array.length > 0){
    //getting an array with the first value in every single of the arrays (eg : [6, 6.5, 5.5])
    array_of_first_values = array.map(obj=>parseFloat(obj[0]))
    //getting the index of the biggest value
    highest_value_index = array_of_first_values.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math,array_of_first_values))
    //pushing the array with the highest value in the first position to our new array, sorted_array
    sorted_array.push(array[highest_value_index])
    //taking away from original array the array pushed to the new one
    array.splice(highest_value_index,1)

  }
  console.log(sorted_array)
  return sorted_array
}

var array =
[[ '6', 235 ],
[ '6.5', 240 ],
[ '5.5', 217 ],
[ '9.5', 249 ],
[ '5', 216 ],
[ '8.5', 230 ],
[ '7', 245 ],
[ '11', 277 ],
[ '4', 210 ],
[ '9', 238 ],
[ '10', 238 ]]


sort_array_by_first_value(array)
```

I hope you find this useful

Comment: thank you it does work in your sample but if I plug it into my function array = [join] (join = [size, sale] it returns this
```[ [ '10', 235 ] ]
[ [ '9', 242 ] ]
[ [ '9.5', 243 ] ]
[ [ '11', 259 ] ]
[ [ '10.5', 255 ] ]
[ [ '12', 269 ] ]
[ [ '8', 234 ] ]
[ [ '8.5', 239 ] ]
[ [ '11.5', 282 ] ]
[ [ '13', 278 ] ]
[ [ '7', 278 ] ]
[ [ '7.5', 259 ] ]
[ [ '14', 285 ] ]
[ [ '12.5', 271 ] ]
[ [ '15', 260 ] ]
[ [ '16', 250 ] ]
[ [ '17', 201 ] ]
[ [ '18', 240 ] ]
[ [ '13', 950 ] ]
[ [ '12', 3500 ] ]
[ [ '9', 4396 ] ]
[ [ '9.5', 2800 ] ]
[ [ '10', 3500 ] ]
[ [ '12.5', 2850 ] ]```

Comment: how are you using the function?

Comment: I have adjusted the main question to include how I am using your function, thanks.